# The wedge of an exact form with a closed form is exact.

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms, exterior-algebra, exterior-derivative

I'm trying to prove that the wedge of a closed form $\xi$ with an exact form $\omega$ is exact. We already have that half of it is exact. Maybe we can use the equation of $\xi$ being closed to rewrite the wedge. Other than that I am sort of stuck.

Comment: If $d \alpha = 0$, then $\alpha \wedge d\beta = \pm d\left(\alpha \wedge \beta\right)$, which is clearly exact.